# SVG Rectangular and Path Gradient

Tags: svg, path, gradient, shapes, effect

I use radialGradient as below to give a tube bulb glow effect :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <radialGradient id="radial" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop  offset="0.8" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#004444"/>
    </radialGradient>

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"
            fill="url(#radial)"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

But how do I do same for Rectangular and Path Gradient or any Custom Shape Gradient for different shapes like rect or star ? 
We have this option in MS PowerPoint which is called as Rectangular gradient and Path Gradient. 
It shud start at center and first stop point 0.8 and second stop at 1 for each edge line just like above effect.

Are these gradients available in Illustrator?

[image: Rect]
[image: Star]

Comment: SVG does not support such gradients.

Comment: You could try to fake it using shadows. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778568/how-to-make-an-inset-drop-shadow-in-svg

Comment: @Austin I tried all in ur link whole night with all combinations.
Nothing gave an effect like this. I have edited my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fake it by splitting the shape into multiple sub-shapes.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <linearGradient id="horiz" x1="0.5" spreadMethod="reflect">
        <stop  offset="0.8" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#004444"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="vert" y1="0.5" x2="0" y2="1" spreadMethod="reflect">
        <stop  offset="0.8" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#004444"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <polygon points="0,0, 100,100, 100,0, 0,100" fill="url(#horiz)"/>
    <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 0,100, 100,100" fill="url(#vert)"/>
</svg>
```

The way this works is that we have two hourglass-shaped polygons, and we apply linear gradients to each.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <polygon points="0,0, 100,100, 100,0, 0,100" fill="gold"/>
    <polygon points="0,0, 100,0, 0,100, 100,100" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the white line/space between the two hourglass-shaped polygons? I am not seeing any white line when using solid fill, but there's a gap when using <linearGradient> as the fill.

In the first example above, there is a thin white line/gap but the same is not visible in the second  example. I want to remove the white line/gap from the first example also.

Comment: Do you mean the thin light-coloured line that goes diagonally out from each corner?

Comment: Yes. It's more prominent when the colors are darker.

Comment: In my original sample, the main cause is the anti-aliasing artifact.  You can get rid of the part of the effect caused by anti-aliasing by using a rectangle for the back-most gradient and overlay an hourglass over the top of it (see https://jsfiddle.net/kw6duvqm/1/).  Unfortunately I don't think you can get rid of the effect completely, because the rest is an optical illusion. The sudden change in pixel colours at the corner results in you seeing a diagonal line.  If you take a snapshot of that "line" and zoom into the bitmap, you will see the line virtually disappears.