# How to create an inset shadow(transparent background) in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I make a simple SVG Icon, but I cannot figure out how to create an inset shadow.

Is it some way to make it?

```css
svg {
  filter: drop-shadow(.1px 1.5px .1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="124" height="124" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1">
 <path  d="M15.668 8.626l8.332 1.159-6.065 5.874 1.48 8.341-7.416-3.997-7.416 3.997 1.481-8.341-6.064-5.874 8.331-1.159 3.668-7.626 3.669 7.626zm-6.67.925l-6.818.948 4.963 4.807-1.212 6.825 6.068-3.271 6.069 3.271-1.212-6.826 4.964-4.806-6.819-.948-3.002-6.241-3.001 6.241z"/>
    
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The final result should be as this one:
[image]

Comment: What is a "star/t board"?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean *borders*. The boarders of the start. @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D sure, I have added the picture of what is should to be in the result

Comment: https://www.xanthir.com/b4Yv0

Comment: I think you cannot do the inset shadow as your star is not a solid shape therefore drop shadow will be put on both sides of the line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778568/how-to-make-an-inset-drop-shadow-in-svg

Comment: @Paulie_D it's not exactly what I need, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a shape that is the outline of the a star rather than the whole shape being a star.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="260" height="245" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="rgb(240, 240, 240)" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1">
   <filter id="inset-shadow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
    <feComponentTransfer in=SourceAlpha>
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
    <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(20, 0, 0)" result="color"/>
    <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      <feMergeNode />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
 <path filter="url(#inset-shadow)" d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z"/>
    
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502987/svg-how-to-create-an-inset-shadow#comment93876435_53502987) had some good resources. I used that and modified it a bit to get you closer to your example image.

**Edit:** Op mentioned in comments that they would prefer a transparent fill. [Source](https://codepen.io/dereklewis/pen/JXOmNe). This is different from [Sviat Kuzhelev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504157/10559113) as this uses one contiguous path for the shape rather than creating multiple disjointed lines.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="inset-shadow" width="200%" height="200%">
      <!-- Shadow Offset -->
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" />
      <!-- Shadow Blur -->
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"  result="offset-blur" />
      <!-- Invert the drop shadow to create an inner shadow -->
      <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" result="inverse" />
      <!-- Color & Opacity -->
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity=".75" result="color" />
      <!-- Clip color inside shadow -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow" />
      <!-- Shadow Opacity -->
      <feComponentTransfer in="shadow" result="shadow">
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <!-- Put shadow over original object -->
      <!--<feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic"/>-->
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path filter="url(#inset-shadow)" d="M12 .587l3.668 7.568 8.332 1.151-6.064 5.828 1.48 8.279-7.416-3.967-7.417 3.967 1.481-8.279-6.064-5.828 8.332-1.151z" />
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, but I need the same svg with the `fill` and `stroke` rules as in the question: `fill="transparent" stroke="transparent"`. In your propose you set `fill='rgb(240, 240, 240)'`. This is not what is need in my particular case. :(

Comment: Ah. That's going to be a bit more complicated as the filter is being applied to the fill. Could you update your question to include the transparent bit? Technically, this answers the question without that caveat.

Comment: Just kidding. I found an example that uses a transparent fill and stroke.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution, but in your case it can help. See my example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="26" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="1" stdDeviation=".3"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

 <path style="fill:transparent; filter:url(#shadow);" filter="drop-shadow(.1px 1.5px .1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5))" d="M15.668 8.626l8.332 1.159-6.065 5.874 1.48 8.341-7.416-3.997-7.416 3.997 1.481-8.341-6.064-5.874 8.331-1.159 3.668-7.626 3.669 7.626zm-6.67.925l-6.818.948 4.963 4.807-1.212 6.825 6.068-3.271 6.069 3.271-1.212-6.826 4.964-4.806-6.819-.948-3.002-6.241-3.001 6.241z"/>
    <path 
     stroke="white"
        fill="white"
        stroke-width="1"
     d="
         M 0 11
            L 0 0
            L 12 0
            L 12 3
            L 9 9
            L 0 10
        "
    />
    <path 
     stroke="white"
        fill="white"
        stroke-width="1"
     d="
         M 0 10
            L 0 30
            L 5 30
            L 5 25
            L 6 15
            L 0 10
        "
    />
    <path 
     stroke="white"
        fill="white"
        stroke-width="1"
     d="
         M 3 30
            L 26 30
            L 26 25
            L 21 26
            L 13 20
            L 2 26
        "
    />
    <path 
     stroke="white"
        fill="white"
        stroke-width="1"
     d="
         M 26 0
            L 26 30
            L 20 30
            L 20 26
            L 18 16
            L 23 10
            L 16 10
            L 13 4
            L 13 0
            L 26 0
 
        "
    />
   
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.
You can play with around `paths` at you own and make them more pretty, I think.