How can I do a drop shadow inside a SVG mask?
I've got an SVG that I'm working on, and I've made a border around my design and "hollowed out" the middle using a mask. Now I'd like to apply a drop shadow to the inside of the border to make it look like it's sitting just above the rest of the elements.
Here's my SVG so far:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="640">
    <defs>
        <!-- The bezel -->
        <mask id="bezelMask">
            <!-- Make everything fully opaque -->
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
            <!-- Then make a circle with a smaller radius -->
            <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="43.75%" fill="black" />
            <!-- Then unmask the bottom part of the bezel -->
            <rect width="100%" height="6.25%" y="65%" fill="white" />
            <!-- And finally, mask everything below that -->
            <rect width="100%" height="35%" y="71.25%" fill="black" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g id="circular-face">
        <!-- Add the bezel -->
        <circle id="bezel" r="50%" height="100%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="red" mask="url(#bezelMask)" />
    </g>
</svg>

I've tried a few different things (<feDropShadow>, CSS styling etc.) but I can't seem to get it to do anything on the masked out portion.
I'm thinking that I need to convert my shape into a path, or at least make a path that sits underneath to make the shadow show up, but now I'm just curious if it's possible to do a drop shadow on the inside of an SVG mask
So can I make a drop shadow that affects the inside portion of a masked out shape?

Just put the drop-shadow on the  circular-face wrapper element. Due to operation order, the mask is applied after the filter, so you need to do it that way. The other option is to do the masking using filter primitives, but that's more complicated than the simple fix.

As commented by Michael Mullany: you need a wrapping <g> element to apply a filter to a masked (or clipped) element. Otherwise, the filter result get's "cut-out" as well.
To apply the inset shadow to the inner shape only you need an extra <mask> defining only this area. Then you can apply a custom inset-shadow filter.
See also "How to create an inset shadow(transparent background) in SVG?".


body {
  background: #ccc
}

.innerShadow {
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#insetShadow);
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="640">
  <defs>
    <!-- The bezel -->
    <mask id="bezelMask">
      <!-- Make everything fully opaque -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <!-- Then make a circle with a smaller radius -->
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="43.75%" fill="black" />
      <!-- Then unmask the bottom part of the bezel -->
      <rect width="100%" height="6.25%" y="65%" fill="white" />
      <rect width="100%" height="35%" y="71.25%" fill="black" />
    </mask>

<!-- mask for inner shape -->
    <mask id="maskInner">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="43.75%" fill="white" />
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" y="65%" fill="black" />
    </mask>

 <!-- based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502987/how-to-create-an-inset-shadowtransparent-background-in-svg#53503687 -->
    <filter id="insetShadow" width="200%" height="200%">
      <!-- Shadow Offset -->
      <feOffset dx="10" dy="10" />
      <!-- Shadow Blur -->
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" result="offset-blur" />
      <!-- Invert the drop shadow to create an inner shadow -->
      <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" result="inverse" />
      <!-- Color & Opacity -->
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity=".75" result="color" />
      <!-- Clip color inside shadow -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow" />
      <!-- Shadow Opacity -->
      <feComponentTransfer in="shadow" result="shadow">
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
      </feComponentTransfer>

    </filter>

  </defs>

  <circle id="bezel" r="50%" height="100%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="red" mask="url(#bezelMask)" />  
  <!-- inset shadow area -->
  <g class="innerShadow">
     <circle id="inner" r="50%" height="100%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="white" mask="url(#maskInner)"  />
  </g>

</svg>



If you don't need to animate the mask you may also opt for a clip-path instead:


body {
  background: #ccc
}


.innerShadow {
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#insetShadow);
}
<h3>Clip-path</h3>
<svg width="640" height="640">
<!-- add rectangular path in counter clockwise drawing direction -->
<path d="M0 0 v640  h640 v-640 z
M600 320c0 33.7-6 66.1-16.9 96h-526.2c-10.9-29.9-16.9-62.3-16.9-96 0-154.6 125.4-280 280-280s280 125.4 280 280z"  />
</svg>

<h3>Inner shape</h3>
<svg width="640" height="640">
   <path d="M600 320c0 33.7-6 66.1-16.9 96h-526.2c-10.9-29.9-16.9-62.3-16.9-96 0-154.6 125.4-280 280-280s280 125.4 280 280z" id="arc" />
</svg>



<h3>Clipped SVG</h3>
<svg width="640" height="640">
  <defs>
  <!-- inset shadow -->
    <filter id="insetShadow" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset dx="10" dy="10" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"  result="offset-blur" />
      <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" result="inverse" />
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity=".75" result="color" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow" />
      <feComponentTransfer in="shadow" result="shadow">
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  
  
  <!-- inner shape -->
   <path d="M600 320c0 33.7-6 66.1-16.9 96h-526.2c-10.9-29.9-16.9-62.3-16.9-96 0-154.6 125.4-280 280-280s280 125.4 280 280z" id="arc" />
    
    <!-- clip-path: negative shape-->
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <!-- add rectangular path in counter clockwise drawing direction -->
         <path d="M0 0 v640  h640 v-640 z
                  M600 320c0 33.7-6 66.1-16.9 96h-526.2c-10.9-29.9-16.9-62.3-16.9-96 0-154.6 125.4-280 280-280s280 125.4 280 280z"  />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <!-- border -->
  <use href="#arc" clip-path="url(#clip)" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-width="80"/>
  <!--inset shadow-->
  <use href="#arc" class="innerShadow"/>

</svg>



In this case we create a <path> element for the inner shape in a graphic editor like inkscape using path-operations like subtract.
We can make this path reusable by creating a <defs> element. The visible stroke can be drawn by an actual stroked instance of the inner shape which is cut-out by a clip-path.
While this approach may appear quite complicated we get a slightly more compact SVG and can circumvent some safari/webkit related mask rendering issues (e.g sometimes rendering these at a fixed resolution resulting in blurry renderings when zooming).
