# Inset shadows on svg are just acting as an outline

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to add some inset shadows to my svg, to make it look more like this

[image]

Instead of like this

[image]

I tried adding an inset shadow to every path (`filter="url(#inset-shadow)"`), using the filter pattern I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778593/6331353) and have listed below, but all it ends up doing is kind of giving each path an outline. You can check the code at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samgermain/0unfLp4r/3/) to see what I'm talking about.

```
<filter id="inset-shadow">

    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha" result="inset-selection">
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1" />
    </feComponentTransfer>

    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="original-no-fill">
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 1" />
    </feComponentTransfer>

    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="original-no-fill" result="new-source-alpha" values="0 0 0 0 0
                      0 0 0 0 0
                      0 0 0 0 0
                      0 0 0 1 0" />

    <feGaussianBlur in="new-source-alpha" result="blur" stdDeviation="5" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="new-source-alpha" result="blur2" stdDeviation="10" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="new-source-alpha" result="blur3" stdDeviation="15" />
    <feMerge result="blur">
        <feMergeNode in="blur" mode="normal" />
        <feMergeNode in="blur2" mode="normal" />
        <feMergeNode in="blur3" mode="normal" />
    </feMerge>

    <feComposite operator="in" in="inset-selection" in2="blur" result="inset-blur" />

    <feComposite operator="over" in="original-no-fill" in2="inset-blur" />
</filter>
```

How can I add inset shadows to my shapes, to make my svg look more like the image at the top of this post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one you are using may have been failing because it was intended for transparent paths.  I didn't spend much time working out what is wrong.

In any case, here's one I've created, that might be a bit easier to understand and tinker with.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="400">

  <defs>
  <filter id="inset-shadow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">

    <!-- change this to desired inset blur colour -->
    <feFlood x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="black" result="flood"/>
    <!-- cut a hole out of the flood fill where out shape is -->
    <feComposite operator="out" in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" result="outside" />

    <!-- stack blurs to get a better effect -->
    <feGaussianBlur in="outside" result="blur" stdDeviation="5" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="outside" result="blur2" stdDeviation="10" />
    <feGaussianBlur in="outside" result="blur3" stdDeviation="15" />
    <feMerge result="blur">
        <feMergeNode in="blur" mode="normal" />
        <feMergeNode in="blur2" mode="normal" />
        <feMergeNode in="blur3" mode="normal" />
    </feMerge>

    <!-- clip the full blur against the shape to retain just the part inside our shape -->
    <feComposite operator="in" in="blur" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inset-blur" />
    <!-- blend with our original graphic to create the final result -->
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="inset-blur" mode="multiply"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  
  
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="linen" filter="url(#inset-shadow)"/>
</svg>
```

And here is a [modified version of your fiddle with this filter applied](http://jsfiddle.net/g79aof2q/).

You may want to tinker with the `stdDeviation` values to adjust the size of your inset blur.